# database for IOT device data

Tags: database, nosql, iot, geocoding

I am new to IOT world.There is a requirement to store geo co-ordinates(Longitude and Latitude) received from iot devices.

1. each device will emit messages in every 10 seconds.
2. Device count will be around 1000 in the beginning.
3. Data will be used to show history and produce analytics.

I am new to IOT as well as no sql world.

Could any one please suggest  what database should be store data?

need to retrieve data based on time and device and several other cases

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you miss any messages fromc your device(s)? What type of analytics are you planning to do? (spatial?) What could be the maximum number of devices?

Comment: data will have gps co-ordinates of moving vehicles and 1 or 2 message missing should be ok.
Device count can grow upto 2000

Analytics such as :
Fuel consumption based on distance.
milage 
History of travel  and many more

Answer (score 0):

I would advise for Oracle Database which comes with advanced Spatial, IoT and analytics capabilities aka a Converged Database: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/toc.htm

Here is a white-paper for IoT: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/in-memory/overview/twp-bp-for-iot-with-12c-042017-3679918.html (talking about relaxed consistency page 13)

You may want to test it with the free release 18c XE for testing purposes... or you may try its free Autonomous version as well (19c available): https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/